# CSS Grid not applying styles to inner children

Tags: css

I am creating a table as below and want to use `display:grid`. But for some reason, the styles within the grid items are not being applied. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
 table-layout: auto;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr min-content;
}

thead,
tbody,
tr {
  display: contents;
}


tbody {
 overflow: auto;
}


thead {
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 4px 0 8px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

tr {
 line-height: 1.5;
 border: none;
 border-collapse: none;
 height: 40px;
 min-height: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(2n){
 background-color: pink;
}

tr:hover {
 background-color: red;
}

td {
 min-height: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 8px;
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="list" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">Date</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Action</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1584748800000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">gt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1584662400000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadasdsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1584576000000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">fdgfdgdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1584144000000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">ACCEPT</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583539200000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">ACCEPT</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583452800000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583366400000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583280000000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">aadasdsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583193600000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583107200000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: With `thead, tbody, tr { display: contents; }`, you are practically “dissolving” those elements, they behave as if they hadn’t been there in the first place, and their children take their place instead. I don’t think you can expect proper results with `tr:nth-child(2n)` any more in that situation …

Comment: @CBroe Do you have any idea how can i make this work then, if i still want to set table to display: grid

Comment: @coffeeak you can check my answer now, I have modified your code as per requirement. You can make code simpler than complicated, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cleaned your code.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: pink;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  min-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="list" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">Date</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Action</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1584748800000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">gt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1584662400000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadasdsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1584576000000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">fdgfdgdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1584144000000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">ACCEPT</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583539200000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">ACCEPT</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583452800000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583366400000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdasdasdsadsadsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583280000000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">aadasdsadsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583193600000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asdas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">1583107200000</td>
      <td role="gridcell">DISMISS</td>
      <td role="gridcell">asd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, can you explain to me what was wrong in the css? and what you changed? thanks!

Comment: I have updated, you have to use hover on the `td` not on `tr`.

Comment: yes, now I understand! I moved the colors to be on td and not tr. thanks!

Comment: Along with that I also modified your code making it clean! hope you like it! kindly vote if you think it is worth voting! thanks.